# How to iterate over arrays, providing access to the element, index, and array itself without using built in Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a JS project where I cannot use any built in JS functions, I must code the solution myself. I cannot seem to get my below function to work. It should not return a value, but simply run the iterator function over each element in the array to provide access to the element, index and array itself. What am I doing wrong? (I am new to JS). I am looking for basic JS solution, not jQuery please.

Sorry, the whole code looks like this:

```
myForEach = function(collection, iterator) {
    for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        iterator(collection[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: You're missing the ending `}` for your function. Otherwise, it looks fine.

Comment: Maybe you also need to give a name to the function?

Comment: Also, `iterator(collection[i])` only provides the element. Passing two more arguments for the index and the array itself should be easy.

Comment: @Phil It's obviously an academic exercise, learning how functions like `forEach` work.

Comment: @JohnMcGuirk Don't try to put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: @Phil If you can't implement `forEach` by yourself, what hope do you have of implementing something complicated?

Comment: @Phil: There are several parts to learning how to program: you need syntax of your language, you need algorithmic thinking, and you need knowledge of your language's library. You seem to assume this last one is sufficient, since this exercise trains the other two. [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) is widely regarded as one of the best intros to programming, and this is pretty much exactly how it starts.

Comment: Sorry all, I tend to forget about academia

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks, that is what I was missing, I was just passing the value, and leaving out the key and collection arguments. Thank you. A slight follow up question, if this collection is an object instead of array, shouldn't for(var val in collection) work for both?

Comment: @Amadan: Thanks for your comment, this is what I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the function a name, and add the missing `}` at the end. Then add the additional arguments that you want to pass to the iterator.

```js
function runIterator(collection, iterator) {
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    iterator(collection[i], i, collection);
  }
}

runIterator([1, "foo", "bar"], function(x, i, c) {
  alert(x);
});
```